Is it possible to create a public website that allows linux systems but blocks windows systems?
Is it possible to create a public website that allows linux systems to connect to it but blocks windows systems? I am familiar with apache2, nginx, bind9, iptables, mitmproxy, etc. But I somehow thought of this question since Microsoft is such a "hairball".

Why would you want to block people based on the OS they use? That is rude.

How would you reliably detect the which OS is connecting, in a way that can't be spoofed?

@ChesterGillon "the can't be spoofed" is a hard ask, but there are things you can do to bolster the reliability of your detection over and above using browser User Agents.

@CPlus Plenty of systems do this - at least to some degree.   Try using Linux and you get a lot more roadblocks thrown up when browsing then with Windows.  His system, his rules.    At minimum its an interesting idea to kick around.

@davidgo I thought this site wasnt about discussions, especially theoretical ones.  :-)  Besides googling will give you ways to try and do it.

You could get a reasonable "First Approximation" by having the server or website check the USER_AGENT string contains the word "Linux" or block "Windows" [you did not specify how to handle OS's other then Windows and Linux, like MacOS, BSD, nor if you define Android as Linux]   This, of-course, can be worked around with a browser plugin or knowledge, but it will cut out most casual use.    Of-course, it will allow many bots through.
Beyond this there are ways to "up your game", but it becomes asymptotically harder -
You can likely "up your game" by doing some browser fingerprinting.  If you really want to go all out you can do some passive OS fingerprinting as well, but I imagine this will be limited information.     (see https://proxidize.com/blog/passive-os-fingerprinting/)
https://kalilinuxtutorials.com/pstf2/ is not exactly "on point" but will open up some ideas and additional strategies.
You may be able to boost the accuracy by causing DNS queries to be made and fingerprinting those as well, but as these typically go through a DNS "proxy" it may not provide much.
